# How to use font awesome 5 icon in laravel blade?

Tags: php, css, laravel, font-face, font-awesome-5

I want to use font awesome icon using @fontface rule. HOw can write styles inside in internal styles inside  tag.

How can can I write the code?

Internal styles written inside head tag

```
@font-face {
font-family: "FontAwesomeRegular";
font-weight: normal;
font-style : normal;
       src : url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/webfonts/fa-regular-400.ttf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
font-family: "FontAwesomeBrands";
font-weight: normal;
font-style : normal;
       src : url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf") format("truetype");
}
@font-face {
font-family: "FontAwesomeSolid";
font-weight: bold;
font-style : normal;
       src : url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/webfonts/fa-solid-900.ttf") format("truetype");
} 

.fas{
    font-weight: bold !important;
     font-family: FontAwesomeSolid !important;
}
.fas::before{
    font-weight: bold !important;
    font-family: FontAwesomeSolid !important;
}
.fab{
    font-weight: normal !important;
     font-family: FontAwesomeBrands !important;
}
.fab::before{
     font-weight: normal !important;
    font-family: FontAwesomeBrands !important;
}
.far{
    font-weight: normal !important;
     font-family: FontAwesomeRegular !important;
}
.far::before{
     font-weight: normal !important;
    font-family: FontAwesomeRegular !important;
}
```

inside blade used  `<i class="fab fa-accessible-icon"></i>`

Comment: What have you got so far? Please post your code and any errors you might get

Comment: there is no error , but icon not showing. you can see how i used in my edited question @brombeer

Comment: please show your html file where you have added all font awesome contents

Comment: it is lengthy that tag i used <i class="fas fa-address-book"></i> @bhucho

Comment: @nithisha do not [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052984/font-awesome-icon-5-not-working-in-generated-pdf-using-dompdf-in-laravel-blade)...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Font awesome icon 5 not working in generated pdf using dompdf in laravel blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052984/font-awesome-icon-5-not-working-in-generated-pdf-using-dompdf-in-laravel-blade)

Comment: @matiaslauriti there is no answer

Comment: @nithisha You have to wait

Comment: go to cdnjs copy the link for font awesome js cdn from there and then either download it and add via offline or directly add link from there in you blade file, if nothing works you can directly use svg from fontawesome website and upload it in your blade for icons

Comment: You might try this if you're able: https://github.com/owenvoke/blade-fontawesome